# Create new dataframe by substracting every column with each other, solving poor performance issues

Tags: python, pandas

Error:

> "DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of
> calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.
> Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.
> To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()"

Code:

```
df_DIFFs = pd.DataFrame()

for a, b in itertools.permutations(df.columns,2):
    df_DIFFs[f'{a}-{b}'] = df[a] - df[b]

df_DIFFs
```

I can't imagine how to use pd.concat or any other more efficient solution in this situation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the advice by storing column differences in a list and then concatenating:

```
# our test df
df = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()

# here we will store columns that are differences
diff_cols = []

# iterate
for a, b in itertools.permutations(df.columns,2):
    tmp = (df[a] - df[b]).rename(f'{a}-{b}')
    diff_cols.append(tmp)

# concatenate
df_DIFFs = pd.concat(diff_cols, axis=1)

output
df_DIFFs
```

output:

```
                   A-B         A-C         A-D         B-A         B-C         B-D         C-A         C-B         C-D         D-A         D-B         D-C
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
igc6RyqBmG   1.02425     1.39726    -0.460256   -1.02425     0.373015   -1.48451    -1.39726    -0.373015   -1.85752     0.460256    1.48451     1.85752
MMIfUNYx8i   1.18588     3.64252     0.0921551  -1.18588     2.45664    -1.09373    -3.64252    -2.45664    -3.55037    -0.0921551   1.09373     3.55037
2MhnKJeZ2K   0.86183     1.00485    -1.12921    -0.86183     0.143022   -1.99104    -1.00485    -0.143022   -2.13406     1.12921     1.99104     2.13406
in9wt14lku  -1.40201    -0.0527898  -1.73563     1.40201     1.34922    -0.333613    0.0527898  -1.34922    -1.68284     1.73563     0.333613    1.68284
7S6tkx2WFN   0.779529    1.40291     0.418794   -0.779529    0.623382   -0.360735   -1.40291    -0.623382   -0.984117   -0.418794    0.360735    0.984117
1C2wmIahde  -2.18965     0.161868   -1.36776     2.18965     2.35152     0.821893   -0.161868   -2.35152    -1.52963     1.36776    -0.821893    1.52963
oRqd898jAl   0.658137    1.58394     0.712051   -0.658137    0.925807    0.0539145  -1.58394    -0.925807   -0.871893   -0.712051   -0.0539145   0.871893
...
```